# Defining Inequality in Construction of Reals

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The following question is from [Construction of Number Systems, Kumar](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Ekumar/courses/310-2012/peano.pdf), page 30. Consider $\Bbb R$ to be the set of all Cauchy sequences of rational numbers under the equivalence relation given in the notes. Define the following relations on $\Bbb R$ for $A=[\{x_n\}]$ and $B=[\{ y_n  \}]$:

$A < B$ if $$\exists \ \ 0<\epsilon_1<\Bbb Q \ \ \exists N_1 \in \Bbb N: \forall \ \ n,m \geq N_1, y_n - x_m > \epsilon_1$$

$A = B$ if $$\forall \ \ 0<\epsilon_2<\Bbb Q \ \ \exists N_2 \in \Bbb N: 
\forall \ \ n,m \geq N_2, \lvert y_n - x_m \rvert < \epsilon_2$$

According to the notes, $$A \leq B \iff \forall \ \ 0<\epsilon_3<\Bbb Q \ \ \exists N_3 \in \Bbb N: \forall \ \ n,m \geq N_3, y_n - x_m > -\epsilon_3$$

I am encountering difficulty in proving $(\Leftarrow)$. Assume $$\forall \ \ 0<\epsilon_3<\Bbb Q \ \ \exists N_3 \in \Bbb N: \forall \ \ n,m \geq N_3, y_n - x_m > -\epsilon_3$$ Further assume that $A \neq B$, that is: $$\exists \ \ 0<\epsilon_2<\Bbb Q \ \ \forall N_2 \in \Bbb N: 
\exists \ \ n,m \geq N_2, \lvert y_n - x_m \rvert \geq \epsilon_2$$

Choose $\epsilon_3 = \epsilon_2$, obtain $N_3$. Choose $N_3 = N_2$. Then there exist $n.m \geq N_2$ for which $y_n-x_m > -\epsilon_2$ and $\lvert y_n - x_m \rvert \geq \epsilon_2$. Then: $$y_n - x_m > -\epsilon_2 \wedge (y_n-x_m \geq \epsilon_2 \vee y_n - x_m \leq -\epsilon_2)$$ So there exist $\epsilon_2$ and $N_2$ for which $y_n -x_m \geq \epsilon_2$.

One problem is that I have $\geq$ rather than $>$. Another problem is that I have shown $\exists n,m \geq N_2$, not $\forall n,m \geq N_2$.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a comment: you say "$\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all rational Cauchy sequences". That is not what your notes say, is it? $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of equivalence classes of rational Cauchy sequences under a certain equivalence relation. And you write $A=\{[x_n]\}$, which is again wrong, it should be $A=[\{x_n\}]$. I'm a bit worried that you are misunderstanding the basic definition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, fixed those errors.